# How do define an event in F# visible from C#

Tags: c#, .net, f#

Looking at various bits of documentation, the way of defining an event in F# is to do something like

```ml
type xyz () =
    let e = new Event<T>
    member x.something_happened : IEvent<T> = x.Publish
```

Unfortunately, the type of IEvent is really Miscrosoft.FSharp.Control.IEvent<_>, and it is hence difficult to use from within C#. Some articles suggest adding the CLIEvent attribute to member something_happended above but it seems to make no difference as far as its usability from C# without including the F# library goes.

How do I correctly define an event in F# so I can then add a delegate to it in C# code? Many thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two event types in F#, [`Event<'T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370608.aspx) and [`Event<'Delegate, 'Args>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370292.aspx). Only the second one is compiled to a .NET event when `[<CLIEvent>]` is present. Here's a working example:

```ml
type T() =
    let e = Event<EventHandler<_>,_>()

    [<CLIEvent>]
    member x.MyEvent = e.Publish

    member x.RaiseMyEvent() = e.Trigger(x, EventArgs.Empty)
```

In some cases the compiler generates a warning if `[<CLIEvent>]` is used with a non-standard event type. I'm not sure why it doesn't raise a warning for your code (perhaps a bug?).

Comment: Many thanks. That has got me much further. Now I want to use the event, I can define "static void OnFinish(object sender, EventArgs e){}", then use += on the newly defined event to register the function. However, I would really rather say "delegate void OnFinish(); OnFinish onfin = () => {};" and then add "onfin" to the event. Could you please me give me a hint on how to do that? Many thanks, and sorry if I am missing some really basic C# knowledge.

Comment: You could do: `EventHandler<EventArgs> onfin = (sender, args) => { };` and then `x.OnFinish += onfin;`.

Comment: how do you trigger an event when you don't have a class instance? (in the constructor for example, I have a situation where I register a handler that reacts to an event itself. There is no class instance in that situation).