# How do I subscribe to an event implemented in F# from a C# client?

Tags: f#

How do I subscribe to an event implemented in F# from a C# client?

I have the following code:

```
_dispatcher.SignInRequested += StartActivity(typeof(SignInActivity));
```

This line results in the following error:

> Error CS0012  The type 'FSharpHandler<>' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'FSharp.Core,
>   Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I attempted to troubleshoot and found [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/65):

However, I do not understand the answer. My events are defined under a namespace and not a module. Hence, me not understanding the reasoning of that discussion.

I then tried adding the following reference to my C# project:

```
FSharp.Core 4.0.0.1
```

and

```
FSharp.Core 3.1.2.5
```

However, I still receive the same error.

When managing Nuget packages, I do not see the version "3.3.1.0" listed as an option.

**Implementation Details:**

The signature of the signin event from the C# client is the following:

```
public event FSharpHandler<Unit> SignInRequested;
```

I actually declare the event as the following:

```
let signInRequested = new Event<_>()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The error means that a) you are leaking F# types and b) Visual Studio added the wrong library to your F# project, even though you target F# 4. I fixed (b) by adding FSharp.Core as a NuGet package to my F# projects and any other projects that needed an FSharp.Core reference. I suspect you'll also run on F# errors when you use syntax that was added in F# 4

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435299/how-do-define-an-event-in-f-visible-from-c-sharp) ? Have you used the `Event<'Delegate, 'Args>` type anc `[CLIEvent]` attribute for the event ?

Comment: No... I have this: public event FSharpHandler<Unit> SignInRequested;

Comment: I declare it like this: let signInRequested =  new Event<_>()

Comment: Use the other form then, as shown in the other question. `Event<_>` doesn't expose a .NET compliant event. On the .NET side you shouldn't need any handler-derived types

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. You can post your guidance as an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at the [CLIEventAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.clieventattribute-class-%5Bfsharp%5D) . Events declared from F# cannot be used from C# unless they are declared with this attribute.